# How to do continuous integration for c# application?

Tags: continuous-integration

Can anyone advise what is the equivalent of hudson for c# application?

I used to use hudson as a build server for java performing auto deployment for java web and batch job application at scheduled timing and email notify technical team

I like to ask how can i do the same for c# application.

And is there any standard plugins like static code analysis tool in the build server which i can used to scan through the codes

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the great tools mentioned by jamesj, [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) works pretty well too.  I prefer it to CruiseControl, from a configuration usability perspective, and it is free given you stay within certain constraints.

If you've already invested in TFS as a source control, though, make sure you are getting your money's worth and use it for your builds and deployments too.

If you like Hudson, take a look at [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).  I've seen folks using it for .NET builds as well, though I haven't personally used it, and according to their page Jenkins used to be called Hudson, so it would probably be familiar to you.

Comment: FYI: Jenkins and Hudson are forks of a common project (Hudson took the name, Jenkins took the original developers). If you are familiar with Hudson, then Jenkins will be very familiar to you.

Answer (score 4):

[TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/ff637362.aspx) is great for continuous integration, but you can also use [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) with [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/). Both of these should be able to run batch jobs, send emails and run automated deployments

[StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) and [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) both do static checking and both can be integrated into your build process.